# simulate union to make indexed view

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, indexed-view

I've got the following table schema in SQL Server 2005 and I'd like to denormalize it into an indexed view for some queries I'm writing until I can make the structural changes permanent.

The tables are as follows

```
Writing
(
DocumentSerial int
Grader1_ID int
Grade_1 int
Grader2_ID int 
Grade_2 int 
Grader3_ID int 
Grade_3 int
)

Users
(userID int,
firstname,
lastname
)
```

I want a table with a single row for each grader/grade/document combination where the grader is either grader 1, grader 2, or grader 3

The View I wrote uses UNION, so it doesn't index:

```
select documentSerial,grader1_id as grader_id, grade_1 as grade ,1 as sequence
 from Writing w inner join User U on w.grader1_id=u.userid
UNION
select documentSerial,grader2_id as grader_id, grade_2 as grade ,2 as sequence
 from Writing w inner join User U on w.grader2_id=u.userid
UNION
select documentSerial,grade31_id as grader_id, grade_3 as grade ,3 as sequence
 from Writing w inner join User U on w.grader3_id=u.userid
```

Problem is - SQL can't index the view with union...

Comment: Do you mean you want to normalize it (instead of denormalize)?

Comment: I wanted to have a temporary normalized structure until I could get the application constructs in place to update a normalized table. Thought a view would do the trick, but alas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why does it have to be an indexed view when you could use a proper table:

```
SELECT x.*
  INTO normalized_table
  FROM (select documentSerial,grader1_id as grader_id, grade_1 as grade ,1 as sequence
          from Writing w 
          join User U on w.grader1_id = u.userid
        UNION ALL
        select documentSerial,grader2_id as grader_id, grade_2 as grade ,2 as sequence
          from Writing w 
          join User U on w.grader2_id = u.userid
        UNION ALL
        select documentSerial,grade31_id as grader_id, grade_3 as grade ,3 as sequence
          from Writing w 
          join User U on w.grader3_id = u.userid) x
```

I understand that you probably want the view so you don't have the hassle of synchronizing data.  The only other alternative is to not index the view...

Comment: Yeah, that was it. Maybe I'll just do the normalized table and write a routine to update it until I can get the app set up. Thanks!